# Python - Zeep error - The message could not be processed

Tags: python, zeep

I am trying to use an Action from an External SOAP API. This API has no documentation so I am in the dark mostly. I got a request working in SOAP API, so I wanted to try in Python which I will use for the integration.

My zeep:

```
wsdl = 'https://asp.external.se/apps/api/service.svc?wsdl'
token = UsernameToken('username', 'password')
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, wsse=token)
client.service.GetCompanies()
```

I can tab through `client.services` and see all the actions, so I know the WSDL is setup correctly.
But I get this error no matter what action I try calling:

> Fault: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'www.external.com/services/apiservice/GetCompanies' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

The one thing I can think of, is that the endpoint that works in SOAP UI is not the default endpoint for the WSDL, I had to manueally add "/endpoint2" in SOAP UI. Not sure if I can do the same in zeep.

Here is the raw envelope that works in SOAP UI:

```
POST www.external.com/services/apiservice/endpoint2
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ".../GetCompanies"
Authorization: Basic Zm9hLWFwaTpGXFGUw==
Content-Length: 1030
Host: asp.external.se
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bril="www.external.com/services/apiservice">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-DE48543B99D24B1D1597402523">
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"></wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">arhKkjhdKuO9yGGw==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2020-08-19T09:59:34.025Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:GetCompanies />
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```